# Is there some how to navigate to a page and pass parameters without use the address bar in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side

This is present in many modern SPA libraries/frameworks...

I will supply an example using React (But it could be Angular or Vue),  you can do something like...

```
this.props.router.push({
  pathname: '/login-successfully',
  state: {
    userId: 'john',
    name: 'John Doe
  }
})
```

and then on the initialization of the "other-page" you will have:

```
const {state} = useLocation();
const { userId, name } = state;
```

and you can render things like

```
<p>Welcome Back, {name}!</p>
```

Such feature is very useful in many scenarios, but by reading the documentation of routing in Blazor at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0 I cannot find anything. The NavigationManager just have those parameters:

```
public void NavigateTo (string uri, bool forceLoad = false);
```

Is there some equivalent approach that I can use ? I know a workaround by creating a singleton class, store the data over there and display on the login-successfully page, but I really hope to find something better as solution.

Comment: Your stated workaround is currently the only approach that can be used with Blazor.

Comment: Why are you averse to using the URL?  The virtue of the Blazor model is that your address bar always reflects a navigable state.  i.e. You can refresh the page (and bookmark it!)

Comment: @Lex, really ? This is really bad. Well, it's a new philosophy of DotNet. Maybe in the future they can improve it.

Comment: @KirkWoll, nah.... an URL like /login-sucessfully?id=123&name=John%20Doe is really absurd. That example that I supplied in React in fact is present in basically all moderns SPA frameworks. Will be very welcomed when it comes to Blazor.

Comment: I agree that it seems to be a shortcoming, but I don't think it's even on the roadmap to implement passing objects during navigation. Every time the subject comes up on GitHub the response is to create a singleton to use as state. This is fine when you have a single user of the application, but becomes just slightly more tricky when you have multiple users - especially if you are configured for anonymous access. I guess another option is to use session storage.

Comment: @MarcoJr but in that example, you can just have the successful login UX be a part of the login page, and change what you're showing based on local state.

Comment: @KirkWoll Simplistic examples are, by their very nature, simplistic. There are certainly legitimate reasons to want to pass an object between pages in a fashion that is native to the framework.

Comment: @Lex, I disagree if they are actually pages.  Pages should be top-level and bookmarkable.  If you want to pass dynamic state (i.e. C# objects or whatever) then it probably shouldn't be a page.  I'd love to learn about a non-simplistic use-case that actually should be a page.

Comment: @KirkWoll Just because a page has the option of receiving an object upon navigation does not absolve the developer of the need to handle the situation where the object is not present. There are times when constructing an object may be an expensive process. For example, an edit page with routes defined accepting an ID as well as no ID. In the latter case I would like to be able to pass the object to be edited if it has already been constructed on another page, rather than have to make a trip to the database (which happens if the ID is passed instead).

Comment: Thanks for elaborating, @Lex, I understand your point.

Comment: An interesting discussion.  It all depends if you are routed (pun intended) in the web page paradigm.  See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5286205/An-Alternative-to-Routing-in-Blazor-2 for a totally alternative "Application Paradigm" approach.  Nowadays, I'm in the middle, but the article was written to challenge the paradigm.

Comment: He He ! Wow ! I think my question create polemic :) Not was my intention ! Sorry ! Anyway, I just illustrated a typical scenario...there is tons of scenarios where things like that will be necessary. All the moderns SPAs frameworks/libraries had this feature. Nobody will bookmark welcome back pages, thanks for your order page, we successfully sent you a new password page, etc, etc and many etc.Of course, this is my opinion, my point of view and I am not the lord of true. I can be wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, my first answer got me a thumbs down, as apparently the decades-old standard of passing data in the URL was "rubbish" (actual quote) so let me explain what I actually do in this kind of case.  I'm not actually a big fan of passing data in a query string either, especially since in Blazor you rarely need to.

I wasn't joking when I said that I wouldn't navigate among pages that share a large amount of data.  I consider each page a separate site, with its own loading and saving of information to the database.  Unless I'm passing something very simple, like an ID in the URL, I would use components to switch sub-functions.

(Not tested code, but you can get the idea)

Main page:
**main.razor**

```
@if (IsDoingSomethingWithData)
{
     <MyDoingSomethingWithDataComponent ID=variable_ID Name=variable_Name State=variableState />
}
else
{
     <input @bind=variable_state /><br />
     <input @bind=variable_ID /><br />
     <input @bind=variable_name /><br />
     <button @onclick="ToggleDoingSomething">Next</button>
}

@code {
     string variable_state;
     string variable_ID;
     string variable_name;
     bool IsDoingSomethingWithData;
     void ToggleDoingSomething(){
          IsDoingSomethingWithData = !IsDoingSomethingWithData;
     }
}
```

Component: **MyDoingSomethingWithDataComponent**

(i.e. the stuff that you would have navigated to, **but in Blazor don't need to**)

```
<div>Hello, @variable_name</div>
<div>Your ID is: @variable_ID</div>
<div>I understand that you live in state: @variable_state</div>

@code{
[Parameter]
string ID;

[Parameter]
string Name;

[Parameter]
string State;
}
```

If you actually make a project and do this-- use named parameters to initialize a component-- you'll see that it never gets hit, and upon inspection of the page, none of the component has been rendered, UNTIL you set IsDoingSomethingWithData = true;

Magic!

Comment: I consider each page a separate site --> You really can't understand the SPA philosophy.